# Determine RGBA colour received by combining two colours

Tags: language-agnostic, colors, rgba

I have two colours defined as RGBA (in my specific examples, one of the set is [white with alpha 0.85] and [57, 40, 28 with alpha 0.25].  The second colour is drawn over the first one (i.e. white with alpha is the background and the second colour is used for drawing).  How can I figure out what the RGBA colour of the combination is going to be?  I need to do this one-off - so any tools is fine (e.g. I'm happy to draw something in photoshop and see what comes out).

I have several sets to combine, but not too many.  Any pointers?  Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

When using [Painter's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Painter%27s_algorithm) most color compositing is done using [Porter-Duff](http://keithp.com/~keithp/porterduff/p253-porter.pdf) "Over" mode:

Resulting alpha:

```
αr = αa + αb (1 - αa)
```

Resulting color components:

```
Cr = (Ca αa + Cb αb (1 - αa)) / αr
```

So for your example:

```
alpha = 0.25 + 0.85 * (1 - 0.25)                        = 0.8875

red   = (57 * 0.25 + 255 * 0.85 * (1 - 0.25)) / 0.8875  = 199.2
green = (40 * 0.25 + 255 * 0.85 * (1 - 0.25)) / 0.8875  = 194.4
blue  = (28 * 0.25 + 255 * 0.85 * (1 - 0.25)) / 0.8875  = 191.1
```

See [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing) on alpha compositing.

Comment: Great, thanks!  Except you seem to have swapped the colours around. If I follow that article, I need to replace the two colours around in your answer.

Comment: Oops, I didn't read the question thoroughly and put white in the foreground. But you're right: Ca is foreground, Cb is background.

Comment: I'm confused by the notation that is used here. Are `a` and `α` the same variable, or are they different variables?

Comment: @AndersonGreen `αa`, `αb` and `αr` are three variables. They designate the first source's (a), second source's (b) and result's (r) alpha components.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe What do `Cr`, `Ca` and `Cb` represent, then?

Comment: @AndersonGreen They stand for all three color components, again r for result, a and b for the sources.