# How to find background color behind transparent image using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I want to select the color for the title which is a text inside an svg. The color has to be darker or lighter depending on the background-color of the body or the div containing the svg. The body may not have any background color specified. How to find background color to understand the theme so that I can decide whether to use darker or lighter color.

NOTE: I am using jquery.colorBrightness.js to understand whether the background color is dark or light

Comment: Ditto - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999209/how-to-get-the-background-color-code-of-an-element

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10781953/determine-rgba-colour-received-by-combining-two-colours