# How to overlay an RGBA image on an RGB image in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

I have a set of RGB images (size (400,200,3)) that I'm animating using matplotlib.animation and I want to overlay an RGBA image (size (400,200,4)) on top of them. It seems that FFMPEG is choking on the alpha data that gets added when I overlay the second image using axes.add_image() (it works fine without the overlay). I was wondering if there is a way to overlay the second image and eliminate the alpha data before I pass it along to matplotlib.animation as I think this will solve the problem.

I'm using python 2.7.9 and matplotlib 1.4.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a two step problem. First you need to combine to RGBA images, then you want to map RGBA -> RGB. Note that mapping your first image from RGB -> RGBA is trivial by setting the alpha mask to fully opaque. Both of these questions have already been solved on SO.

1. **Combining RGBA + RGBA**:

   [Determine RGBA colour received by combining two colours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10781953/determine-rgba-colour-received-by-combining-two-colours)
2. **Mapping RGBA -> RGB**:

   [Convert RGBA color to RGB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049230/convert-rgba-color-to-rgb)